Help with understanding Inverse Discrete Fourier transform
I am trying to program a simple implementation of Inverse discrete Fourier transform. I thought I understood, but something in my understanding is obviously lacking since my results are wrong.
For a minimal example, I first use a common Fourier transform implementation (numpy) and Fourier transform these values: $1, 1.6, 0$, which gives the result: $2.6+0.j,         0.2-1.38564065j, 0.2+1.38564065j$.
Now I want to do my own implementation of inverse Fourier transform.
I've seen this formula describing the Inverse Fourier transform:
$a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_ncos(2nt\pi)+b_nsin(2nt\pi)$
where a and b are the Fourier coefficients.
I thought I could transform the complex Fourier values back to the time domain (the original sampling domain) by doing:
$2.6 + 0.2cos(2\pi*t)-1.38564065sin(2\pi*t)+0.2cos(4\pi*t)+1.38564065sin(4\pi*t)$ which would give me a function I could use to calculate the original samples. But if I run this function with the values $0,1,2$ it gives the result: $3,3,3$. Which obviously isn't the same samples as the original.
Obviously my understanding of the results of the Discrete Fourier transform is wrong. I thought that $a$ is the real parts of each value, $b$ is the imaginary. Can someone help me understand how I should think?

Did you read the documentation for numpy.fft.ifft?

Perhaps this answer I posted on MSE provides some insight.
